# Generating a continuous heatmap with uneven sampling in x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I'm trying to create a heatmap using some unevenly sampled data. Originally, when, applying the code

```
ggplot(df,aes(x,y,fill=z))+geom_tile()
```

I get a heatmap that looks like this:

[image]

Now, I'm interested in further exploring the values of x around 0.1. I sample the data and generate a new heatmap using the same line of code, and now my heatmap looks like this:

[image: r]

My guess is that now ggplot doesn't know how to generate the rest of the plot to make it look continuous. I was thinking in trying to fill the gaps using the tidyr fill function, but I'm not entirely sure of how to make this approach. Is there another way, just using ggplot functions? Here's a sample of how the data looks like:

```
sample_df<-structure(list(x = c(0.51, 1.61, 1.41, 1.61, 0.91, 0.01, 0.31, 
1.71, 1.11, 0.21, 0.31, 0.31, 0.61, 0.71, 1.71, 1.91, 0.51, 1.41, 
0.08, 0.065), y = c(0.0811, 0.0561, 0.0701, 0.0891, 0.0251, 0.0221, 
0.0011, 0.0641, 0.0271, 0.0551, 0.0501, 0.0971, 0.0171, 0.0171, 
0.0611, 0.0801, 0.0021, 0.0401, 0.0811, 0.0511), z = c(0.778151250383644, 
0.477121254719662, 0.477121254719662, 0.477121254719662, 0.602059991327962, 
Inf, Inf, 0.477121254719662, 0.477121254719662, 1.11394335230684, 
0.903089986991944, 0.954242509439325, 0.602059991327962, 0.602059991327962, 
0.477121254719662, 0.477121254719662, Inf, 0.477121254719662, 
2.05307844348342, 2.34439227368511)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), spec = structure(list(
cols = list(epsilon = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), mu = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), eta = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), N0 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out myself. Since the spacing of my data is around 0.1, I can make the width of each tile to be 0.1 and it will fill the whole space.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x,y,fill=z))+geom_tile(width=0.1)
```

gives the desired plot

[image]